# struct pointer problems in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

the line  `Printing("testing ",H->Name)` causes a compiler error:

`expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char **'`

But i tried with many pointer-combinations, but I need help for this

````
 struct header {
     char* Name[257];
     ... };
 
 void Printing(char * string,char * val) {printf("%s
 [%s]",string,val);}}
 
 int main () {
 
  struct header *head = malloc (sizeof(struct header));
 
  func(header);
 
 }
 
 void func( struct header * H) {
 
 FILE * FP = fopen("test.t","r"); if (FP == NULL) {return 0;}
 
 fscanf(FP,"%s\n",H->Name);
 
 Printing("testing ",H->Name);
 
 fclose(FP);
 
 }```
````

Comment: `char* Name[257];` should probably be `char Name[257];`. For any further help please provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should update your struct to following,

```
 struct header {
   char Name[257];
 ... };
```

Comment: The answer would be more helpful if you explained just why you suggest that. (What do the two definitions mean?)

Comment: `char Name[257]` is a char array. `char* Name` is a char pointer.   But `char* Name[257]` is char array pointer. It means you define 257 char pointer.

Comment: Put that in the answer to give a rationale for your solution ;-).

Answer (score 0):

in your struct you are declaring a 2D array not 1D array that's why the error pups up.

to fix this error you can use two ways:

1- first one is to declare a normal array using `char Name[257]`.

```
struct header {
   char Name[257];
 ... };
```

2- second way is using pointer :

```
struct header {
     char* Name;
     ... };

int main () {
 
  struct header *head = malloc (sizeof(struct header));

  head->Name = malloc (sizeof(char) * 257);
  func(header);
 
 }
```